# Where do the .exe file of a Ms Visual application goes to?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, air, exe, filepath

Where do the .exe file of a Ms Visual application goes to? I've just created it and I would like to know so that I can execute it from AIR with parameters.
ex of code on AIR:

```
var f:File = new File ("C:\path\application.exe -" + param1 + " -" + param2)
f.openWithDefaultApplication()
```

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: as in you just made the app in vs? The exe is in your debug folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets build in your bin folder.

If you right click on your project and select "Open folder in Windows Explorer", you will find the bin folder and all your project files in there.

Default for windows is.

C:\users\"User account"\My Documents\Microsoft Visual studio 2010\Projects\

Answer (score 0):

It goes wherever you tell it to.

It usually comes from `bin\Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

It gets put into the Bin folder of the project.

within the Bin, there may or may not be seperate folders for Debug and Release builds

Answer (score 0):

It goes to bin/debug or bin/release usually. You can configure it in Project properties.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging

```
var f:File = new File ("C:\users\"UserAccount"\My Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Projects\"Project Name"\"Name"\bin\debug\"NameofApp".exe -"" + param1 + " -" + param2) f.openWithDefaultApplication()
```

If you built it and are looking for it it will be in your bin/release:

Like so.

```
var f:File = new File ("C:\users\"UserAccount"\My Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Projects\"Project Name"\"Name"\bin\release\"NameofApp".exe -"" + param1 + " -" + param2) f.openWithDefaultApplication()
```